# Display route between two points in installed application

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

How to showActivity which will display route between two points.

This will start installed map application on android phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found how to do it.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr=startLat%20startLng&daddr=endLat%20endLng&hl=en");
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,URI);
startActivity(it);
```

Where startLat, startLng, endLat, endLng - coordinates.(38.899533,-77.036476,....)